# CMY colour function in R

Tags: r

Is there a [CMY colour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) function in any R package equivalent to `rgb()`?  There seems to be nothing in {base} or e.g. {colourSpace}.  I have a custom function which I can post here, but a native would be preferable.

Comment: `library(sos); findFn("cmyk")` doesn't find anything useful, so it might not exist.  Surprising.

Comment: I wrote a function `XYZ2lab` if that's any help. I know that's not the colorspace you asked for, but let me know and I'll email it or post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this should work

```
#' assumes integer input for CMYK
cmyk <- function(C,M,Y,K) {

  C <- C / 100.0
  M <- M / 100.0
  Y <- Y / 100.0
  K <- K / 100.0

  n.c <- (C * (1-K) + K)
  n.m <- (M * (1-K) + K)  
  n.y <- (Y * (1-K) + K)

  r.col <- ceiling(255 * (1-n.c))
  g.col <- ceiling(255 * (1-n.m))
  b.col <- ceiling(255 * (1-n.y))

  return(col2rgb(sprintf("#%02s%02s%02s",
                     as.hexmode(r.col), 
                     as.hexmode(g.col), 
                     as.hexmode(b.col))))

}

> cmyk(0,50,85,0)
      [,1]
red    255
green  128
blue    39

> cmyk(0,0,100,0)
      [,1]
red    255
green  255
blue     0
```

Comment: or you can just whack the division and specify CMYK percentages in decimal format. there are a couple other optimizations that cld be made but it gets the job done :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're into code porting,  I found a couple MatLab Central possibilities:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25350-fit-multi-dimensional-polynomial
(despite the name, the description says 'CMYK to Lab'

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45723-convert-rgb-image-to-cmy-image-and-extract-each-component-cyan-c-magenta-m-and-yellow-y

EDIT: if you'd like to invert hrbmstr's code, here's some javascript which can trivially be converted to R  Courtesy of http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgb2cmyk.htm ):

```
 if (r==0 && g==0 && b==0) {
  computedK = 1;
  return [0,0,0,1];
 }

 computedC = 1 - (r/255);
 computedM = 1 - (g/255);
 computedY = 1 - (b/255);

 var minCMY = Math.min(computedC,
              Math.min(computedM,computedY));
 computedC = (computedC - minCMY) / (1 - minCMY) ;
 computedM = (computedM - minCMY) / (1 - minCMY) ;
 computedY = (computedY - minCMY) / (1 - minCMY) ;
 computedK = minCMY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in addition to @hrbrmstr's function here is mine for what its worth. I haven't factored in black as I understand that's primarily for printing but I'd see this primarily as a dataviz tool.  It should work with vectors / matrices / alphas.

```
cmy = function(c, m, y, alpha, maxColorValue=1){
  if(maxColorValue != 1) { c <- c/maxColorValue; m <- m/maxColorValue; y <- y/maxColorValue }
  c <- 1-c; m <- 1-m; y <- 1-y
  hex <- function(v) substring(rgb(v,0,0),2,3)
  if(!missing(alpha)) alpha <- hex(alpha) else alpha <- ''
  paste0('#',hex(c), hex(m), hex(y), alpha)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way of using CMYK colors instead of RGB for printing purpose. If you set the `colormodel` to CMYK, you can use CMYK colors.

Read the details on this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289805.html) and an example [here](http://onetipperday.blogspot.in/2012/10/draw-figures-in-cmyk-mode-in-r.html)

Comment: Yes I saw that page. But unless I'm missing something it just specifies the colourspace for output files.  Its not a function you can use in R to map variables to cyan, magenta or yellow channels and return e.g. a hexadecimal colour string.

Comment: @geotheory As per what I know and sadly you cannot do that. You can use your own function to map RGB to CMYK and vice versa. I assumed that you are using CMYK for printing to reduce gamut.

Comment: Actually I'm just trying to create data visualisations using an alternative to rgb :)  Lets see if anyone else knows a solution.