# Using CMYK colors in heatmap.2 function in R

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I am only able to provide a vector of colors to the heatmap.2 function in R if they are in the HEX format (e.g., "#9D0A0A"). Is it possible to provide a list of colors in CMYK format (e.g., 90,33,100,60)? Or is there another heatmap function in R that allows a list of CMYK colors?

Comment: Can you give a little more context for why you want to do this/what you're trying to do?  Would being able to translate CMYK to RGB colours be sufficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMY colour function in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352568/cmy-colour-function-in-r)